# Android Java Permission

Tags: java, android

Am trying to implement permission here, it works but the callback method for the permission does not get called

```
void checkPermissions(){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){

        new OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
                if(requestCode==1&&grantResults.length>0){
                    for(int x=0; x<grantResults.length; x++){
                        if(grantResults[x]!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Not Yet Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    //call data here
                }
            }
        };
       requestPermissions((Activity) context,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},1);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

Comment: when you call CircularProgressIndicator()? when you call in initState, it will not show toast

Comment: You're just creating the `OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback` and not doing anything with it. You're not assigning it to a variable or anything.

Comment: use `dexter`  library its simple and stable for get permission privilege in android https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter